# MS SQL Server GETDATE - 90 where -90 not like previous

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Today for me is 2017-08-02 13:00:00.000 and I have this table :

```
TABLE1        

    TIME                            NAME        PRODUCT
    2014-10-10 08:34:57.000         Bob          Glu
    2015-11-03 13:34:27.000         Bob          Finger
    2017-07-08 09:51:46.000         Bob          Note
    2017-07-08 09:51:46.000         Bob          PC
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Bob          Car
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Bob          Ball
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Bob          Shoe
    2017-04-01 08:34:57.000         Alex         Pen
    2017-06-03 13:34:27.000         Alex         Horse
    2017-07-31 05:51:46.000         Alex         Bread
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Alex         Hummus
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Alex         Kitchen
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Alex         Hell
    2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Alex         Night
    2016-10-10 08:34:57.000         Eva          Mouse
    2017-05-03 13:34:27.000         Eva          Cement
    2017-06-31 06:51:46.000         Eva          Pc
    2017-06-31 03:51:46.000         Eva          Bread
    2017-06-31 08:51:46.000         Eva          Shoe
    2017-06-31 07:51:46.000         Eva          Ball
    2017-06-31 07:51:46.000         Eva          Zoo
```

I need to know which **PRODUCT** was lost from the above table, but I need to know only **PRODUCT** which was lost from last (**TIME** + **NAME**)  and – 90 days. I expect results like this:

```
TABLE1

    TIME                           NAME         Product

    2017-05-03 13:34:27.000         Eva          Cement
    2017-06-03 13:34:27.000         Alex         Horse
    2017-07-08 09:51:46.000         Bob          Note
    2017-07-08 09:51:46.000         Bob          PC
```

The table has millions of names and millions of products. At the moment I am interest for 90 days from the last updates.

I am trying

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE  (TIME > getdate ()- 90) AND (TIME not like getdate ()- 90)
```

Comment: are you trying to figure out the first thing each person lost in the past 90 days? and include all ties?

Comment: How is a product "lost" exactly? Can you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `where DATEDIFF(day, TIME, GETDATE()) < 90`

Comment: this give me last dates is well i need only previous ones

Comment: What 'last dates'? like more than 90 days ago? When do you want the 90 days to start counting from?

Comment: last days is :
2017-06-31 08:51:46.000         Eva 
2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Alex
2017-07-31 09:51:46.000         Bob

Comment: @Luka Change `<` to `>`

Comment: As @NenadZivkovic said, if you're looking for more than 90 days, change <  to >. If you're looking to start counting from a specific date, then change GETDATE() do that date

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows from the previous 90 days from today.

```
select * from table1
where TIME >= getdate()-90
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to figure out the first thing each person lost in the past 90 days? and include all ties?

Lets limit data and add a window function in a cte and then limit the data to just #1's

```
;with cte as 
(
  SELECT * , DENSE_RANK() over (partition by [name] order by [time]) as DR  
  from table1
  WHERE [time] >= dateadd('d',-90,getdate()) 
)

select *
from cte
where dr=1
```